# Italians/The Italians - using the definite article

Tags: definite-article

Which one of these sentences is correct:

1. Italians drink wine;
2. The Italians drink wine.

Answer (score 1):

You could hear both statements from native speakers. When referring to a nation, to speak of its customs for example, it is clearer and therefore preferred to use the definite article if  your intention is to speak of the nation:

> The Italians drink wine.  The Russians drink vodka.  The Irish drink Guinness.

But in the colloquial speech of a native speaker you might well hear this:

> Italians drink wine.  Russians drink vodka.  The Irish drink Guinness.

There, the zero-article is understood to refer to "all Italians" or "all Russians".

You can also refer to the nation via an imaginary exemplar, a single individual:

> The Italian drinks wine. The Russian drinks vodka. The Irishman drinks Guinness.

It is also the case that a number of these terms must be used with the article. For example:

> British drink tea. <sup>not idiomatic</sup>
>
> Irish drink Guinness. <sup>not idiomatic</sup>
>
> French drink wine.  <sup>not idiomatic</sup>

Comment: The Italians = the country of Italy
Italians = Some people from Italy?

Comment: The Italians (in your example)  =  the people who are the nation of Italy *Il popolo d'Italia*

Answer (score 0):

When you are speaking about Italians in general, you don't use the article - "Italians are good people". In case you are speaking about a specific group of Italians, you can use "the" article - "The Italians that we met at the conference were friendly".

Comment: You are wrong - https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/134226/11912